# when #define a variable , what different between @interface @ implementation and in .h

Tags: ios, objective-c

.h

```
@interface AdvancedSearchMainVC : UIViewController
```

.m

```
#import "AdvancedSearchMainVC.h"

@interface AdvancedSearchMainVC ()

@end

@implementation AdvancedSearchMainVC
```

which is the best location to add `"#define HIDEBUTTON_TAG 100"` and why

what's the different between macro definition  at  @interface @ implementation and  in .h

thx a lot~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the only difference is scope. If you define it in the interface, anything that imports the header can also access the value, whereas if you put it in the implementation it can only be accessed by that class's methods.